# Autohotkey hotstring doesn't work with colon

Tags: autohotkey

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html.read)

::hotstring:: '< this doesn't work
(
Nokogiri::HTML
)
```

When I try to make that line as a hotstring in Autohotkey, it does not seem to work. I tested some variations and realized that the colons ::, when included, sort of breaks that hotstring and it doens't work.

How can I make the above code into a working hotstring?

Answer (score 2):

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm says:

> `` `:: ``  (literal pair of colons). In v1.0.40+, it is no longer necessary to escape these.

However, this doesn't really seem to be true: Your hotstringi doesn't work for me either.

Still, if you escape the `::` as shown in the link, it'll work for you.

```
::hotstring::
(
Nokogiri`::HTML
)
```

Answer (score 1):

See "Ending Characters" in [the AutoHotkey documentation for Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

> Unless the asterisk option is in effect, you must type an ending character after a hotstring's abbreviation to trigger it. Ending characters initially consist of the following: -()[]{}':;"/\,.?!`n `t (note that `n is Enter, `t is Tab, and there is a plain space between `n and `t). This set of characters can be changed by editing the following example, which sets the new ending characters for all hotstrings, not just the ones beneath it:

In other words, remove the colon from `EndChars` like this:

```
#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{};'"/\,.?!`n `t
```

Comment: Hmm... This is odd I added that line of code to my .ahk file and tried, still doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: @1tntla you shouldn't accept it as the solution then, otherwise ppl will not look into this question

Comment: @Andrew, I am not sure, but I think computer restart is required after the EndChars are declared, or Complete closing of Autohotkey application. I use the restart function in autohotkey to test your answer, and it didn't work. Today, I had another hotstring with colon and it worked without the escaping.